# #Ajax change the input wrapper

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

i've made a form which update the price of a product. The user just need to select a duration by a select-list and it update the price by an Ajax callback. It update well the price but it change the structure of my select and then the select when is changed again does nothing...

The form inputs :

```
$key = array('field_friterie_suggest', 'MY-PRODUCT-SKU');

$form['content']['deals'][$key[0]]['purchase']['value'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#name' => 'update-price-'.$key[0],
            '#options' => array(               
                5 => t('- None -'),
                0 => t('1 month'),
                1 => t('3 month'),
                2 => t('6 month'),
                3 => t('1 year'),
            ),
            '#default_value' => $default_purchase_value,
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'fritr_commerce_update_pricing_callback',
                'wrapper' => 'pricing-'.$key[0],                
            ),
            '#attributes' => array(
                'data-update' => array(
                    'pricing-'.$key[0],  
                ),
                'data-type' => array(
                    $key[1],  
                ),
            ),
        );        
        $form['content']['deals'][$key[0]]['purchase']['pricing'] = array (
            '#prefix' => '<div class="pricing" id="pricing-'.$key[0].'">',
            '#suffix' => '$</div>',
            '#markup' => 0,
        );
```

And my callback :

```
$month = $form_state['triggering_element']['#value'];
    $price = 0;
    if ($mont != 5) {
        $month_definition = array(1,3,6,12);
        // get the product by his SKU
        $product = commerce_product_load_by_sku($form_state['triggering_element']['#attributes']['data-type'][0]);        
        // get the product price and reduction
        $product_base_price = ($product->commerce_price[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['amount'] / 100) * $month_definition[$month];
        $reduction = $product->field_commerce_reductions[LANGUAGE_NONE][$month]['value'];        
        // set the new price
        $price = $product_base_price - ($product_base_price * ($reduction/100));                    
    }
    return array (
        '#prefix' => '<div class="pricing" id="'.$form_state['triggering_element']['#attributes']['data-update'][0].'">',
        '#suffix' => '€</div>',
        '#markup' => $price,
    );
```

So my input become :

```
<select data-update="pricing-field_friterie_suggest" data-type="MY-PRODUCT-SKU" class="form-control form-select ajax-processed" id="edit-content-deals-field-friterie-suggest-purchase-value" name="update-price-field_friterie_suggest"></select>
```

to :

```
<div class="form-item form-item-update-price-field-friterie-suggest form-type-select form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <select data-update="pricing-field_friterie_suggest" data-type="MISE-EN-AVANT-SITE" class="form-control form-select ajax-processed" id="edit-content-deals-field-friterie-suggest-purchase-value" name="update-price-field_friterie_suggest"></select>
        <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then when i change the value of the select, it does nothing. Can you help me please ?

Comment: You are adding form elements in your ajax callback. This can't/won't work. All changes to the form need to be made in the form definition, as the form is already cached before the callback. Also, $form_state['#rebuild'] needs to be set in either the submit function, as it will not work in the ajax callback.

Comment: yes the form rebuild is a test i do to try to fix the bug but without it the bug is the same ^^

Comment: As I said, you cannot add/alter form elements in the ajax callback. It has to be done in the form definition.

Comment: Ahhh ok i understand i just need to put in my ajax callback a $form_state['#rebuild'] = TRUE; then and in my form definition do the treatment ^^ i do the modifications and i back here if i had some questions

Comment: Almost. $form_state['rebuild'] needs to be in the submit function. It will not work in the ajax callback.

Comment: Then what did i need to put in my ajax callback if i don't do the changes here and if the $form_state['rebuild'] need to be in the submit function ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45908/discussion-between-kpone-and-jaypan).

Comment: It is worth to post the answer here if this question is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by Jaypan works well.
The solution was to not put the modifications of my field in the callback but in the form definition and set the value here by checking the $form_state fields.